# Kernel Panic after replacing CMOS battery

Tags: centos, kernel

We have a Centos 5.8 system that was experiencing CMOS battery errors, which we resolved by replacing the battery. However, after replacing the battery, the system displays a "kernel panic" error message every time it boots up.

[image: Kernel PANIC]

What steps can we take to resolve this issue, and are there any additional details that would be helpful to know?

Comment: My theory is that when you replaced the battery you reset CMOS - thereby resetting BIOS settings to a default state, incompatible with the state the BIOS was in when you installed Centos

Comment: Your kernel doesn't see your HDD. As to why, I've no idea. Considering RHEL 5 hasn't been supported for almost a decade and its hardware requirements, it's high time to move this system to a VM and isolate it.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll have to look into the BIOS settings once I am in front of the system.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Would I have to do a clone of the drive to a VM? This almost sounds like a last resort, but still a possible option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages

> No volume groups found

> mount: could not find filesystem '/dev/root'

all hint to that the kernel can't find the disk containing the root filesystem.

While the disk can be accessed by the BIOS and the bootloader using the BIOS, it seems like it is inaccessible using the Linux drivers built in the kernel or provided by the initramfs under the current BIOS settings.

On most mainboards the BIOS settings are kept in volatile memory that is kept alive by the CMOS battery when the system is not connected to a power supply.
By removing the battery all BIOS settings were likely reset.

You should check if the BIOS has settings for an SATA controller mode. Many BIOSes support running the SATA controller in "Legacy", "AHCI" or "RAID" mode. If this setting exists, try out "Legacy" or "AHCI" and check if it boots.

"RAID" mode *may* cause data loss if it wasn't setup that way initially, so make a backup before trying it out.

Comment: Thanks alot! Changing the configuration to AHCI fixed the issue!